# SearchBar: dynamic change results

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, searchbar

Try to make a search bar with constantly updating table view depending of letter I tap. Like here: https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2019/08/candy-typing.gif

```
extension EmotionsContoller: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {



    if searchBar.text!.count > 1 {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Array> = Array.fetchRequest()

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    loadArray(with: request, predicate: predicate)
    }
    }

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
        loadArray()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }

    }
}
```

What I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload data of your tableView

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
        loadArray()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        } else if searchBar.text!.count > 1 {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Array> = Array.fetchRequest()

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)

         request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

         loadArray(with: request, predicate: predicate)
         tableView.reloadData()
    }

    }
```

Comment: After what line I need to do this?

Comment: `loadEmotions(with: request, predicate: predicate)` after this line

Comment: Tried. Same thing - a table reload after I tap enter

Comment: if you want to change array on text change ... you need to do that in textDidChange and reload data

Comment: I want my tableView to change dynamically every time I enter a new letter. Now it changes only after I enter some letters and tap Enter. tableView.reloadData() didnt help.

Comment: check the answer ... try it and let me know please ... it will work on every letter change sir

Comment: Yes, it works! I've tried a lot of variants but not this one. It was close) Thank you!